# Как уменьшить слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, css

Взял от сюда слайдер - https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/WwVKLN, и он в итоге растянулся на всю страницу, в том числе на другие объекты. Примерно так это выглядит: Как его уменьшить и расположить внизу объектов? Я уже всё перепробовал. Вот мой полный код, если что - https://jsfiddle.net/4mxdLcre/ Тому, кто поможет - скину 100 на киви

```css
*/
.carousel {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
/**
  * Where the magic happens
  */
/**
    * Control element - right/left arrows
  */
/**
    * Element for holding slide indicators
  */
/**
    * Indicator for indicating active slide
  */
/**
    * Create rules for when slides are contained within a track
  */
}
.carousel__controls,
.carousel__activator {
  display: none;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(4) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-400%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(5) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__control {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fafafa;
  opacity: 0.35;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.carousel__control:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__control--backward {
  left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.carousel__control--forward {
  right: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.carousel__indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel__indicator {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.35;
  margin: 0 2.5px 0 2.5px;
}
.carousel__indicator:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.carousel__track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: translateX(300%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: translateX(400%);
}
.carousel--scale .carousel__slide {
  transform: scale(0);
}
.carousel__slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
/**
  * Theming
*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  background-color: #111;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.carousel-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.my-carousel {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.carousel__slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicator {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fafafa;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
h2,
h3 {
  color: #fafafa;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.carousel__indicator {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/300?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/600?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/900?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1200?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1500?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <h2>slider</h2>
  <div class="carousel my-carousel carousel--translate">
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="F" checked="checked"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="G"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="H"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="I"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="J"/>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="J"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="G"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="F"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="H"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="G"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="I"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="H"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="J"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="I"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="F"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__track">
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>F</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>G</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>H</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>I</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>J</h1>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__indicators">
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="F"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="G"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="H"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="I"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="J"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы скопировали с ошибками код, слайдер 400px на 300px

```css
.carousel {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel__controls,
.carousel__activator {
  display: none;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(4) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-400%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(5) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__control {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fafafa;
  opacity: 0.35;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.carousel__control:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__control--backward {
  left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.carousel__control--forward {
  right: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.carousel__indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel__indicator {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.35;
  margin: 0 2.5px 0 2.5px;
}
.carousel__indicator:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.carousel__track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: translateX(300%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: translateX(400%);
}
.carousel--scale .carousel__slide {
  transform: scale(0);
}
.carousel__slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
/**
  * Theming
*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  background-color: #111;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.carousel-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.my-carousel {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.carousel__slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicator {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fafafa;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
h2,
h3 {
  color: #fafafa;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.carousel__indicator {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/300?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/600?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/900?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1200?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1500?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <h2>slider</h2>
  <div class="carousel my-carousel carousel--translate">
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="F" checked="checked"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="G"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="H"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="I"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="J"/>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="J"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="G"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="F"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="H"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="G"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="I"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="H"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="J"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="I"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="F"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__track">
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>F</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>G</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>H</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>I</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>J</h1>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__indicators">
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="F"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="G"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="H"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="I"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="J"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```